# Generalization of appending item to a container

Tags: haskell

I have `Map k [v]` and the function that takes a key and a value, and:

- if the key is in the map, it prepends value to the list that is located by this key.
- if the key is not present, it creates list with one value and puts it in the map at this key.

It's simple, here it is:

```
insertToListMap :: Ord k => k -> a -> Map k [a] -> Map k [a]
insertToListMap k v = M.alter (appendToMaybeList v) k

appendToMaybeList :: o -> Maybe [o] -> Maybe [o]
appendToMaybeList x Nothing = Just [x]
appendToMaybeList x (Just xs) = Just $ x : xs
```

Now I want the same functionality but for `Map k (Set v)`. Basically, now I need

```
insertToSetMap :: Ord k => k -> a -> Map k (Set a) -> Map k (Set a)
```

Is there a way to generalize the function I already have? As I understand, I need generalization of "prepend (append) item to container" and "make empty container" actions. Is there a type class that does this and includes both list and set? Something similar to monoids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I have currently:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import           Data.Map.Lazy (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M

class Appendable c i where
    singleton :: i -> c i
    append :: i -> c i -> c i

instance Appendable [] a where
    singleton x = [x] 
    append = (:)

instance Ord a => Appendable Set a where
    singleton = Set.singleton
    append = Set.insert

insertToMapOfAppendables ::
    (Appendable vs v, Ord k) => k -> v -> Map k (vs v) -> Map k (vs v)
insertToMapOfAppendables k v = M.alter (Just . maybe (singleton v) (append v)) k
```

I'm not satisfied with it because I assume that the problem is generic enough that someone should have already made a library with the class that I need, so it would be overkill to roll out my own implementation of `Appendable` in my simple utility library.

Current answers to this question are basically suggesting to implement instances manually. If there is some library or common approach that should be used instead, I would rather use that.

---

Update: I'm marking this answer as accepted. If there is a better approach to this problem, please answer with explanation and I'll mark your answer as accepted instead.

Comment: note it is not in the scope of stackoverflow to recommend libraries

Comment: *Asking* for recommendations is off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: I guess, I read that last paragraph - as if it was a question.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you are not using `adjust` or `insertWith`?

```
insertToSetMap :: (Ord k,Ord a) => k -> a -> Map k (Set a) -> Map k (Set a)
insertToSetMap k v = M.alter (appendToMaybeList v) k


append' :: (Ord o) => o -> Maybe (Set o) -> Maybe (Set o)
append' x Nothing = Just $ Set.singleton x
append' x (Just xs) = Just $ Set.insert x xs
```

I think a bit easier would be to use

```
insert' :: (Ord k,Ord a) => k -> a -> Map k (Set a) -> Map k (Set a)
insert' k v = Map.insertWith (Set.union) k (Set.singleton v)
```

### Update:

```
import Data.Monoid

-- singleton x = [x]
import Data.Set (singleton)

insert' :: (Ord k,Monoid m) => k -> m -> Map k m -> Map k m
insert' = Map.insertWith (<>)

insertToContainerMonoid k v = insert' k (singleton v)
```

You can have it a bit more generic if you make a `class Singleton` that abstracts over having singletons. Otherwise you need to comment in/out respective parts of your code or put it in separate modules.

### Update2:

Inspired by the idea @ChadGilbert posted as an answer I created the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Lib where

import           Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

import           Data.Map.Lazy (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as Map

import           Data.Monoid

class Container c where
    type Elem c
    singleton :: Elem c -> c

instance Container [a] where
    type Elem [a] = a
    singleton x = [x]

instance Ord a => Container (Set a) where
    type Elem (Set a) = a
    singleton = Set.singleton


insertToContainer :: (Ord k, Container c, Monoid c) =>
    k -> Elem c -> Map k c -> Map k c
insertToContainer k v = Map.insertWith (<>) k (singleton v)
```

This can be used as follows

```
*Lib Data.Map.Lazy> insertToContainer 3 4 Map.empty :: Map Int [Int]
fromList [(3,[4])]
*Lib Data.Map.Lazy> insertToContainer 3 4 Map.empty :: Map Int (Set Int)
fromList [(3,fromList [4])]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful (although I presume, using `insertWith` on map of lists would be inefficient) but the question is more about making the function that works on both lists and sets. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [`Unfoldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/collections-api-1.0.0.0/docs/Data-Collections.html#g:2) typeclass in the `Data.Collections` module (collections-api package).

You only need to define an `insert` function:

```haskell
class Unfoldable c i | c -> i where
    insert :: i -> c -> c
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems it, but do I need to implement instances for list and set myself or is there a library that does it already?